# Eclipse Juno, CDT, ARM, path issues on OS X

Tags: c, eclipse, path, arm, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse Juno, trying to get the ARM toolchain working. What I have installed:

- Eclipse Juno
- [Zylin Embedded CDT Plugin](http://opensource.zylin.com/embeddedcdt.html)
- [GNU ARM Eclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuarmeclipse/) plugin
- [Summon-Arm-Toolchain](https://github.com/esden/summon-arm-toolchain/), installed in the default ~/sat/ directory.

When I create a new C project using the Summon toolchain, the following error appears: 'Program "arm-none-eabi-gcc" not found in path.' The error location is "[Discovery Options] page in project properties."  I've tried setting the Eclipse-level (Eclipse->Preferences->C/C++->Build->Environment) PATH and the project-level PATH to include this path, both relatively (~/sat) and absolutely /Users/alterscape/sat), but nothing seems to fix the problem. I've also tried manually adding the full path in the Discovery Options page. Is there a known fix? If not, is there a way to echo $PATH inside Eclipse to see what it thinks its path is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's the story: Eclipse CDT does NOT automatically re-check errors to see if they go away after you apply changes to your path. You have to manually re-build.  This came as a surprise to me because I am used to my Java toolchain checking/updating errors as I make configuration changes.  It isn't entirely obvious that you need to re-run Build Project to see if your changes fixed the error, but that's the path forward.